# How did Chi end up in the trash?

Tags: chobits

In Chobits, the protagonist finds Chi discarded with trash behind some house.

> One would think a product of a secret project like that, containing some extremely important secrets, would be at the very last disposed of in a responsible manner, and not just thrown out.

Maybe I wasn't an attentive watcher but I never spotted any backstory as to how she ended up there. Does the show explain it? If not, are there any viable theories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the manga, Chitose Hibiya mentions that she hoped someone would find Chii and give her all the things she was missing (e.g. Love). Chii's memory was wiped because she was sad, so this was an attempt to start over from scratch without any of her painful memories. And this also means not knowing anything about Chitose.

So Chitose put Chii in the trash so that Hideki would find her.

Comment: A very far-fetched line of thinking but I guess if that's canon, we've got to accept.

Comment: @SF. I don't think Chii was placed there *specifically* for Hideki, just that he happened to be the one to find her. But yeah, whoever found her could have turned out to be a creep.

Comment: Or a garbageman with a garbage truck, just doing his duty...

Comment: CLAMP tend to be really romantic, so it's exactly their style to have such a reason, even if it would seem far-fetched normally. Tsubasa is overflowing with this stuff.